# Why does sum behaves differently to the plus (+) operation

Tags: python, sum

How come sum does not behave like the plus operator?
How can I use sum on my class?

```py
class Item:
    def __init__(self, factor):
        self.factor = factor

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Item(self.factor + other.factor)


print((Item(2) + Item(4)).factor) # 6
print(sum([Item(2), Item(4)]).factor) # TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Item'
```

itertools.reduce with operator.add also works but it's a lot of typing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the `start` argument of `sum` to an object of type `Item` as its default is an object of type `int` as in stated in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum): `sum(iterable, /, start=0)` where `0` is an `int`.

```
print(sum([Item(2), Item(4)], start=Item(0)).factor)
```

Comment: Thank you, it's not very polymorphic. I'd have to know what's been passed to sum before calling it. Another type of item might have a different __init__ so I don't know the start value. I thought it could act on all things add-able.  Would be good if the class knew its own base case

Comment: Rather than improving the sum expression, it might make sense to improve the `__add__` method. @rosscosack you should ask yourself whether `Item(1) +0 == Item(1)` makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

This is because `sum` returns *sum of a 'start' value (default: 0) plus an iterable of numbers*

```
>>> help(sum)
Help on built-in function sum in module builtins:
    
sum(iterable, /, start=0)
    Return the sum of a 'start' value (default: 0) plus an iterable of numbers
```

So this is equivalent to `0 + Item(2) + ...` hence the `TypeError`!. Instead of 0, You could pass `Item(0)` as default value.